# variable returning null while running jasmine test

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have implemented jasmine test and testing my method.While running the test values of previousItem  is null. If i hardcode the value of previousitem to 20000000, it returns true which is fine. How do i initialize previousitem value in my test.

Please note the the first element in the array would contain minSize : 0 and maxSize: 20000000.

```
    isMinValid(currentItem: any, item_IDX: number) {
        if (item_IDX === 0) {
          return true;
        }

        let previousItem = this.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items[item_IDX - 1];
        if (+currentItem.minSize !== +previousItem.maxSize  ) {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }


beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        TooltipModule.forRoot(),
        FormsModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: { provide: TranslateLoader, useClass: TranslateFakeLoader }
        })
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: BsModalRef, useClass: BsModalRefStub },
        { provide: BackendProxy.ReferenceProxy, useClass: ReferenceProxyStub },
        { provide: RunService, useValue: runServiceStub }
      ],
      declarations: [DomicileSelectionComponent, YesNoPipe, CLICK_INPUT_DIRECTIVE, ShortNumberFormatPipe]
    });
  });

     beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DomicileSelectionComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        comp.domicileInfo =  domicileInformationDataResult.data;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });


        fit('should return true because the current item min value is equal to the previous max value', () => {
            comp.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items = [{maxSize: 30000000 , minSize: 20000000 , values: [2 , 2]}];
            let isMax: boolean = comp.isMinValid(comp.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items[0] , 1);
            console.log(isMax);
            console.log(comp.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items);
            expect(isMax).toBe(true);
          });
```

Component code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { Base } from '@wtw/toolkit';
import * as BackendDto from '../../../../api/dtos';
import * as BackendProxy from '../../../../api/proxies';
import { IModalConfirmation } from '@wtw/platform/interfaces';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { RunService } from '@wtw/platform/services';
import { CONSTS } from '../../../../config';

const minCapRequirement = 'minCapReq';
const premuimTaxCap = 'premTaxCap';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-domicile-selection',
  templateUrl: './domicile-selection.component.html'
})
export class DomicileSelectionComponent extends Base.ReactiveComponent implements OnInit, IModalConfirmation {
  domicileInfo: BackendDto.DomicileInformation;
  public data: any;
  public onClose: Rx.Subject<boolean>;
  public active = false;
  public currentSelectedCurrency = '';
  public domicileId: number;
  public domiciles: BackendDto.Domicile[];
  public amendAssumptions: string;
  fieldCategories: typeof BackendDto.DynamicFieldCategory = BackendDto.DynamicFieldCategory;
  private domicile: BackendDto.Domicile;
  private _selectedIndustries: BackendDto.Industry[];

  constructor(
    private _bsModalRef: BsModalRef,
    private _refProxy: BackendProxy.ReferenceProxy,
    private _runs: RunService,
    private _translate: TranslateService

  ) {
    super();
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.onClose = new Rx.Subject();
    return [this._runs.activeRun.subscribe(r => {
      this.currentSelectedCurrency = r.currencyInfo.currentSelectedCurrency;
    })];
  }

  public show() {
    this.domicileId = this.data.domicile.id;
    this.domicile = this.data.domicile;
    this.domiciles = this.data.domiciles;
    this._selectedIndustries = this.data.selectedIndustries;
    this.domicileInfo = this.domicile.domicileInformation;
    this.amendAssumptions = this._translate.instant('CAPTIVES.DOMICILES.AMENDASSUMPTIONS', { domicile: this.domicile.name });
    this.active = true;
  }

  public close() {
    this.hide(null);
  }

  public udpatevalue(item, value) {
    item.maxSize = value;
  }
  public ok() {
    this.data.domicileId = this.domicileId;
    this.data.domicileInfo = this.domicileInfo;
    this.hide(true);
  }

  public cancel() {
    this.hide(false);
  }

  isMinValid(currentItem: any, item_IDX: number) {
    if (item_IDX === 0) {
      return true;
    }
    debugger;
    let previousItem = this.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items[item_IDX - 1];
    if (+currentItem.minSize !== +previousItem.maxSize  ) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }


  isMaxValid(currentItem: any, item_IDX: number) {
    if (item_IDX === 0) {
      return true;
    }

    if (+currentItem.maxSize <= +currentItem.minSize ) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  domicileChanged($event) {
    if (this.domicileId === this.domicile.id) {
      this.domicileInfo = this.domicile.domicileInformation;
    } else {
      this._loadInformation();
    }
  }

  private _loadInformation() {
    this._refProxy.getDefaultDomicileInformationForClient(this.domicileId, this._selectedIndustries[0].id)
      .uiSignal('infos')
      .subscribe(ret => {
        this.domicileInfo = ret.data;
        const domicileName = this.domiciles.find(x => x.id === this.domicileId).name;
        this.amendAssumptions = this._translate.instant('CAPTIVES.DOMICILES.AMENDASSUMPTIONS', { domicile: domicileName });
      });
  }


  private hide(nextVal?: boolean) {
    this.active = false;
    this.onClose.next(nextVal);
    this._bsModalRef.hide();
  }

  get addnDomicileDetailMinCapReq(): BackendDto.DomicileAddnDetail {
    return this.domicileInfo.addnDomcileDetails.find(x => x.fieldInfo.key === minCapRequirement);
  }

  get addnDomicileDetailPremuimTaxCap(): BackendDto.DomicileAddnDetail {
    return this.domicileInfo.addnDomcileDetails.find(x => x.fieldInfo.key === premuimTaxCap);
  }

  get maxCurrency() {
    return CONSTS.general.maximumCurrencyValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `beforeach()` code??

Comment: posted. I am not sure if its because of null value issue as when i try to debug in chrome browser, i am getting null for all test methods that work properly. May be i am missing something else

Comment: Sorry I am not get it.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `fixture.detectChanges();`.

I hope this below solution will solve your problem.

```
fit('should return true because the current item min value is equal to the previous max value', () => {
    comp.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items = [{maxSize: 30000000 , minSize: 20000000 , values: [2 , 2]}];
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let isMax: boolean = comp.isMinValid(comp.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items[0] , 1);    
    expect(isMax).toBe(true);
  });
```

### edit:

And also you have missed to configure the testing module in testbed. So check this below

```
beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [YourModules],
            declarations: [YourComponent],
            providers: [
                { provide: CreateVersionService, useClass: MockCreateVersion }//providers
            ]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DomicileSelectionComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        comp.domicileInfo = domicileInformationDataResult.data;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
```

Comment: No. that didnt make any difference

Comment: Can you post your component constructor?

Comment: I have updated my answer. and let me know your other methods are working good??

Comment: i had missed sharing one more beforeEach. Please see my updated post. I dont think the issue is with beforeEach. As I mentioned in the post if i hardcode the value in my method for previousItem , i get the correct response. So i feel for some reason while exevuting the test the previousitem must not be getting initialised